# Finding the function $S.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f: U \to \mathbb R^2$ be a function ( $ U \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is open and) with continuous inverse $g =  : V \to \mathbb C,$ where $ V \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and  is also open and it is the range of $f.$ Let $p \in V$ and assuming that $ f'(g(p)) \neq 0$ and $f$ is complex differentiable at the point $p$ in $\mathcal U.$

How can I show that $g$ is complex differentiable at $f(p)$ and $$g'(p) = \frac{1}{f'(g(p))}.$$

**The definition of complex differentiability I know is:**

A function  $f:  U \to \mathbb R^2$ is complex differentiable at a point $p$ in $ U$ if there exist a function $S: U \to \mathbb R^2$ that is continuous at $p$ such that $f(z) = f(p) + S(z) (z - p)$

for all $z \in U.$
**My questions:**

1-I know that we are proving that the inverse of a complex differentiable function is complex differentiable at $p.$ But I am wonderi g how can I find the $S$ function corresponding to the inverse? Is it just the reciprocal of the S function of $f(z)$ which we know from the definition?

2- Why the domain of $f'$ is $g(p)$? And how can I prove this formula $g'(p) = \frac{1}{f'(g(p))}$?

Any. Clarification will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any point in the image $f(U)$ is by construction in the domain of $g$. Therefore $f()=()+()(−)$ is the same as saying
   $$
   f()=()+(g(f())[g(f(z))−g(f())].
   $$
   Moreover, as $p,z$ are arbitrary, $f(p),f(z)$ are abitrary in $f(U)=$dom$(g)$. Rewriting this gives
   $$
   g(u) = g(w) + \frac{1}{S(g(u))}(u-w),
   $$
   where we set $u := f(z), w := f(p)$. This tells you what $S$ is for $g$.
2. The formula $g' = 1/(f' \circ g)$ follows from the fact that $S_g = 1/(S_f \circ g)$ above. The condition $′(())≠0$ is needed to ensure that  $g'$ exists as you can see from the fact that you need to take $1/(f' \circ g)$ to compute the derivative.